# Iarse dynamic Website with Jsoup

Tags: java, web, jsoup

I want to parse this [website](http://www.boerse-go.de/jandaya/#!Ticker/Feed/?n=TopNews).
Jsoup will help me I think. I want all articles seperated, so my try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.boerse-go.de/jandaya/#!Ticker/Feed/?n=TopNews").get();

        Elements ereignisse = doc.select("div#TickerFeed div.articles div.item article.cf"); 

        for (Element e : ereignisse) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But there is no output...

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! The reason you aren't seeing any output is that the Elements that you're selecting don't have any text content.

Try replacing:

```
System.out.println(e.text());
```

with:

```
System.out.println(e.html());
```

to see what I mean.

Comment: Ok i understand...is there any other possibility to get the Text from the Website in my Java Program?

Comment: Not that I can see. The content is generated using JS. So unless you run the scrape using a headless browser (like Selenium) then you're a bit stuck.